# Error message inadvertently included in file output

Tags: unix, sed, output

I'm new to UNIX so I'm hoping people will be able to help me.

So, I have a file that contains a long string that traverses multiple lines.  The string is made up of data that are delimited by a comma.  An example is:

```
"patchId":"29301631-EE", "patchId":"28655784-EE", "patchId":"28090523-EE", "patchId":"28090523-EE", "patchId":"28090523-EE", "patchId":"29301631-EE", "patchId":"29301631-EE", "patchId":"29301631-EE", "patchId":"28655784-EE", "patchId":"28655784-EE", "patchId":"28090523-EE",
```

I am using SED to identify the commas in order to add newlines, so that the data appears as a list.  I then save this output into a file called 'temp'.  The code I use to do this is:

```
(sed 's/\([,] \)/\n\1/g;s/\([,][0-9]\)/\n\1/g' < $patchesAvailable) > temp 2>&1
```

The problem I'm having, however, is that extra information is being added to the file.  Please see below:

```
./vmCompleteScript.sh: line 22: "patchId":"29301631-EE",
"patchId":"28655784-EE",
"patchId":"28090523-EE",
"patchId":"28090523-EE",
"patchId":"28090523-EE",
"patchId":"29301631-EE",
"patchId":"29301631-EE",
"patchId":"29301631-EE",
"patchId":"28655784-EE",
"patchId":"28655784-EE",
"patchId":"28090523-EE",: File name too long
```

For some reason './vmCompleteScript.sh: line 22: ' is being included on the first line and ': File name too long' is being included on the last line, when all I want is a file containing a list of "patchId":"...",

I don't know how to prevent the excess information being added so I'm hoping someone does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using sed to replace commas with newlines...don't.  Instead just do `tr , \\n < input-file`.

Comment: Hi William.  Thank you for taking the time to respons.  I inputted your suggestion and it has definitely improved readability.  Would you know, per chance, how to remove the superflous information detailed above?

Comment: You need to show more context.  It feels like the value in `$patchesAvailable` is possibly a string that contains whitespace and the shell is trying to split it and pass multiple paths to `sed`, at least one of which is a very long string.  Reduce your problem to its minimal form.

Comment: the superflous info is coming from someplace else, most likely the shell. You need to debug your script by running each command separately on the cmd-line, saving each output into a tempPartN file, and then identify which step is generating the error messages. Then you can fix that step. Agree that this sounds like there are spaces the shell is processing. Until you find a reason not to, surround all variable references in dbl-quotes, i.e. `"$myVar"` . Good luck.

Comment: Actually, as you save each step into it's own `tempPartN` file, you're likely to see the error messages appear in the terminal, before the next command prompt. OR you can do each cmd section an `cmd_to_test > tempPart01 2>&1`. Good luck.

Comment: Hello everyone.  Thank you all for taking the time to help.  I found that the trouble was that I was attempting to load the information into a variable before using sed to add newlines.  I think the problem was that the variable wasn't able to hold that amount of data, so I dropped the use of a variable and loaded the file contents straight to SED.  That seemed to have resolved the issue and I can now save the list into a new file without issue.

Comment: Post your working code answer and then accept it (after 24-48? hrs) and gain valuable reputation points. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

2>&1 will direct the error messages to your output. You probably want to direct them to /dev/null i.e. 2>/dev/null

Now all those errors will go to the big bit bucket in the sky ;)

Comment: Hi Jon.  I appreciate your time in this.  I followed your example but this now results in a completely empty file.  Could you guide me in being able to save my list of patchId's only without the ./vmCompleteScript.sh: line 22: or : File name too long   ?

Comment: I mean just use 2>/dev/null **instead of** 2>&1.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll assume that the command line you show is indeed line 22 of `vmCompleteScript.sh`.)

Obviously, although not clearly described, the *string* is contained in the variable `$patchesAvailable`. By writing `command < $patchesAvailable`, you specify the string content as a *file* name, hence the error message `./vmCompleteScript.sh: line 22: string: File name too long`, where `string` is the multi-line name you stated - so, actually no *extra information is being added*, it's just one error message with the erroneous file name in the middle.

To provide the string content as input to a command (`sed` in your case), you have to write:

```
echo "$patchesAvailable" | sed …
```